# Getting mod_deflate working on Apache for a PHP app on Heroku's Cedar stack

Tags: apache, heroku, mod-deflate

How can I get mod_deflate on Apache and Heroku Cedar with a PHP app? I have mod_deflate importing and rules set set in my htaccess, yet my responses won't gzip.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're still interested in solving this problem, but here goes. A lot of this is going to depend on how you've set your dyno up.

If you're running the [Heroku PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) with Apache, [the buildpack version of Apache comes with mod_deflate pre-installed](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/af4116428a93c58b782e1c2edb7e0256eb11c917/support/build/apache#L44).

Even if you're not running the Heroku PHP buildpack, there's some chance that **mod_deflate** might be pre-installed. You can check by running a bash prompt on a one-off dyno and using **apache2ctl** to list all available modules:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.9057

$ $(which apache2ctl || which apachectl) -M
Loaded Modules:  
  core_module (static)  
  ...  
  deflate_module (shared)  
  ...
```

After ensuring that **mod_deflate** was installed and enabled, I then used the .htacess configuration recommended by [html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess#L680) to compress textual MIME types. I added this config to my apache config, but I would think it would work from .htaccess too. After deploying the new configuration, **mod_deflate** worked as expected.

Hope this helps!